# how to convert python httplib.HTTPSConnection to php

Tags: php, python

i want send a post HTTPS request with php ,similar this request in python:

```
API_HOST = "android.clients.google.com"
API_PAGE = "/market/api/ApiRequest"
parmas=params = urllib.urlencode({
  "version" : 2,
  "request" : request
})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection( API_HOST )
connection.request( "POST", API_PAGE, params, headers )
resp = connection.getresponse().read()
connection->close()
```

I tried to this lib 
https://github.com/dcramer/php-httplib

but this lib , not support HTTPS

my php code:

```
$query_data = array(
  "version" => 2,
  "request" => $request
);
$params = http_build_query($query_data);
$headers = array("content-type"=> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$API_URL =  $API_HOST.$API_PAGE;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

python code works, but php code return Bad Request, Error 400

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<?php

// Data
$postfields = array(
    'version' => 2,
    'request' => $request
);

// Post It
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.clients.google.com/market/api/ApiRequest');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Debug
var_dump($result);
```